# What is the difference between Oracle's "sequence" and MySql's Auto_increment feature?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I don't completely understand the difference between Oracle's sequence and MySql's auto_increment.

I am a mysql guy, but know nothing of oracle. I'm hoping someone can shine a quick light on this for me.

Comment: A sequence is more like a rule rather than a primary key column

Comment: Quickly: There are some *very* significant differences: AUTO_INCREMENT is tied to a column in a single table, only one per table. Oracle SEQUENCE is not. On database restart, for InnoDB table, AUTO_INCREMENT is reset to highest column value. Oracle SEQUENCE is not. An Oracle SEQUENCE object is an entirely separate object, designed for generating unique values, with low contention/high concurrency. (It's true that we can emulate MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT using SEQUENCE and BEFORE INSERT trigger, but "at the end of the day", Oracle SEQUENCE bears little resemblance to AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: If the question is: "Can we emulate MySQL-style AUTO_INCREMENT in Oracle?" The answer to that question is yes. If the question is about differences... Oracle sequence: can have lower and upper bound; can have negative value for increment; can wrap (after reaching an upper bound, start again the specified lower bound); new values can be retrieved with a SELECT statement, doesn't require an INSERT; single sequence can be used by a multitude of different triggers, functions, procedures; can be dropped/recreated independent of any table; value of SEQUENCE is retained across database restart, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A sequence is a distinct database object in Oracle.

In MySQL, when you have an autoincrement column and you INSERT a new row in a table, you simply don't mention the autoincrement column and MySQL puts it there.  You can then insert the same number into another table by referencing `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

```
 INSERT INTO person  (name, date)                             /*MySQL*/
                 VALUES ('joe', '2015-01-01');
 INSERT INTO contact (person_id, phone)
                 VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '555-1212');
```

In Oracle, you can populate an id column by mentioning a sequence object's `.nextval` property. You can get the just-used value of that sequence by referencing its `.currval` property.

```
 INSERT INTO person (id, name, date)                         -- Oracle
                   VALUES (person_seq.nextval, 'joe', '2015-01-01');
 INSERT INTO contact (id, person_id, phone)
                   VALUES (contact_seq.nextval, person_seq.currval, '555-1212');
```

Each time you mention the sequence's `.nextval` property, it's guaranteed to give a new number.

Sequence objects are pretty cool when you need unique numbers that aren't directly related to the primary key of some table or other.  You can do this in MySQL, but it's a kludge: If you create the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE sequence (                                       /*MySQL*/
     sequence_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_id`)
)
```

Then issue these three queries one after the other:

```
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES ();                            /*MySQL*/
DELETE FROM sequence WHERE sequence_id < LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS sequence;
```

The third query is guaranteed to return a unique sequence number. This guarantee holds even if you have dozens of different client programs connected to your database. (The `DELETE` query merely keeps this otherwise pointless table from taking up too much space.)

With Oracle, you create the sequence

```
create sequence seq                                           --Oracle
```

and then just do

```
SELECT seq.nextval FROM DUAL                                  --Oracle
```

to get a new sequence number and that's it. It too guarantees uniqueness even with dozens of connected client programs.

Similarly, if you need the value of a sequence you just generated with `.nextval`, you can issue this command and get it.

```
SELECT seq.currval FROM DUAL                                 --Oracle
```

As with MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, this is handled session by session so another client using the sequence won't make you get their number instead of yours.

Bottom line: both DBMSs can generate unique integers. The integrity of both schemes is designed to be preserved across server stops and restarts. The Oracle sequence is more flexible.

Comment: This is a great technique for MySQL. Much much better than trying to keep a sequence in a control table. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

A sequence in Oracle DB is a separate entity which you can access in your queries to get/increment its value and you can use the same sequence with more than one table/field.

Auto increment in MySQL is bound to a single field in a table and used to define the value of that field, when it is not given in the insert query.

Comment: Not only "in theory" can we use the same SEQUENCE for multiple tables, we do that "in practice" as well.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for the clarification, I don't have much experience with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't have auto increment columns. You need to create a sequence and before insert trigger that reads NEXTVAL from the sequence and sets the value for the column

Comment: Ok so at the end of the day the functionality is identical - the sequence is no more powerful than the auto_increment?

Comment: yes you are right in oracle you have to put an extra detail on any numeric column of any table to be auto increment

Comment: @DanielBaughman: If your takeaway is "**the functionality is identical**", then this is a poor answer, because they are fundamentally *different*, there are some *significant* differences in the features. (As this answer does point out, it is possible for us to emulate the MySQL-like AUTO_INCREMENT within Oracle, and the emulation can make effective use of an SEQUENCE object to do that, but Oracle SEQUENCE is *way* more than just AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: i am saying that sequence can perform what auto increment is

Comment: if you are using oracle12c you can simulate auto_increment declaring a number column like: `id number generated as identity`

Comment: yes,Create another table with a single row and column that stores the next id value. Then create an insert trigger on the original table that increments the value in the second table, grabs it, and uses that for the ID column on the first table

Comment: @Aramillo: yes and an identity column is implemented using a sequence. Gives a good view of the difference.